# How to convert numbers to the first letters of the alphabet?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with content like

```
12345
```

I need to convert this kind of strings like this:

```
"0"->"a"
"1"->"b"
...
"9"->"j"
```

So, `12345` should result in `abcde`. I want to achieve this via the shell (bash). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You might note that if `a`⟶`0`, `b`⟶`1`, then `12345` should map to `bcdef` and not `abcde`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In any shell, you could use:

```
echo "$string" | tr 0123456789 abcdefghij
```

Or, in Bash and without a pipe:

```
tr 0123456789 abcdefghij <<< "$string"
```

(where the double quotes might not be necessary, but I'd use them to be sure).

Comment: fixed a bug in your 2nd example

Comment: This does not work for all letters of the alphabet

Comment: @RoelVandePaar — it doesn't try to work for all letters; that isn't the task.  It converts digits 0 to 9 to letters a to j.  How do you think it should work “for all letters of the alphabet”?

Comment: There are several alternative ways of specifying the digits and letters. Both `'0-9'` and `'[:digit:]'` map to 0123456789, and `'a-j'` maps to `'abcdefghij'`.  The single quotes are a good idea around the (verbose) `'[:digit:]'` term; the others do not need the single quotes, but they do no harm either.  I don't recommend the character class, but `tr 0-9 a-j` is succinct.

Answer (score 8):

```
 echo 12345 | tr '[0-9]' '[a-j]'
```

Comment: Say if I have to do the aliter. Map words to numbers. Which is, a->1, b->2 ... and so on.
Why doesnt ``echo hello | tr '[a-z]' '[1-26]' `` work?

Comment: @user3426358 Because sed only translates single characters. Even the translation `tr 'z' '26'` alone is not possible. See also [Is there a tr for translating into longer strings](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16281/is-there-a-tr-for-translating-into-longer-strings).

Answer (score 2):

With sed's map operator.

```
sed 'y/12345/hWa!-/' <<< '2313134'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr 0123456789 abcdefghij < filename
```

Comment: `tr` is a pure filter - it ignores filename arguments

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do it:

```
perl -lnaF -e 'print map chr($_+97), @F' file
abcdefghij
```

Comment: That's pretty obscure and indirect, even for Perl.  It might be appropriate to use the `tr///` operator...but then, it is Perl and TMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 1):

Easy method in `bash` if you're okay with using arrays.

```
alphabet=({A..Z})
number=8
letter="${alphabet[$number]}"
```

With this method, A will be 0, B will be 1, etc.

If you instead want A to be mapped to 1, just change the array value to this.

```
alphabet=('' {A..Z})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works for **all** letters of the alphabet ([with thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855773/1208218)):

```
inputnr=1  # a
declare -i i=$[ 97-1+${inputnr} ]
c=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $i))
echo "char:" $c
```

```
inputnr=26  # z
declare -i i=$[ 97-1+${inputnr} ]
c=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $i))
echo "char:" $c
```

Comment: To make the output uppercase `A-Z` for `1` to `26` as input, do: `c=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $i) | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')`

Comment: Under your scheme, what would 12345 be converted to?  The question indicates that it should be either 'abcde' or 'bcdef'.  It certainly seems to want to transform each digit separately.   People quite often use 'number' instead of 'digit', especially if English is not their first language.

Comment: The question does not specifically state that all numbers need to be converted at once.