# shell script - is there any way converting number to char?

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer ASCII value to character in BASH using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890262/integer-ascii-value-to-character-in-bash-using-printf)

I want to convert my integer number to ASCII character

We can convert in java like this:

```
int i = 97;          //97 is "a" in ASCII
char c = (char) i;   //c is now "a"
```

But,is there any way in to do this shell scripting?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# chr() - converts decimal value to its ASCII character representation
# ord() - converts ASCII character to its decimal value

chr() {
  printf \\$(printf '%03o' $1)
}

ord() {
  printf '%d' "'$1"
}

ord A
echo
chr 65
echo
```

**Edit:**

As you see `ord()` is a little tricky -- putting a single quote in front of an integer.

> The Single Unix Specification: "If the leading character is a
>   single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in
>   the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or
>   double-quote."

(Taken from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071).

See [man printf(1p)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html).

Comment: it works but i want to set variable like `var=$(printf \\$(printf '%030' $1))` thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

```
declare -i i=97
c=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $i))
echo "char:" $c
```

Comment: Can you explain the part `printf \\$(printf '%03o' $i)`?

Comment: @CharlesW.`printf '%03o' $i` converts from decimal to octal (`97` -> `141`). Then passing it with "\\" which printf understands (i.e. `printf \\141`) and prints a char for the octal sequence.  From *info printf*:`'printf' interprets '\OOO' in FORMAT as an octal number (if OOO is 1 to 3 octal digits) specifying a character to print, and '\xHH' as a hexadecimal number (if HH is 1 to 2 hex digits) specifying a character to print.`

Comment: I think the `03` zero padding is unnecessary?

Comment: For completeness: `printf "\x$(printf "%x" "$i")"`