# convert input to string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[How to convert numbers to the first letters of the alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031176/how-to-convert-numbers-to-the-first-letters-of-the-alphabet)  . I want to use this code for me. But I need alphabets for `10,11,12,13` etc. for example if the user will enter `10` , the program will print `j` for `11 -->"k"` . How cam I do this.
My code is same in the link above

Comment: You can write a method that uses ASCII values for this.

Comment: you are right @MichaelLiberman

Comment: Try `printf \\\x$(printf '%x' input)`. For example: `for input in {1..26}; do printf \\\x$(printf '%x' $((input+96))); done`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this BASH function:

```
cnvt() { printf "\x$(printf '%x' $((97 + $1 -1)))\n"; }
```

**Test it:**

```
cnvt 10
j
cnvt 11
k
cnvt 26
z
```

Comment: What I have in my answer is indeed the shell script. Just add my given inside any shell script and use it the way I suggested here.

Comment: for example , when I write 35 , it gives me 'z' .Is it possible ? I know when I write 26 i gives 'z' . but ıt is possible for in ascii codes ?

Comment: `cnvt 35` prints a printable character i.e. ASCII code 132

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASCII table for this.
If user inputs 10 you can add 87 and get "a" = 97.
This way input 11 will get a value of "b" = 98.